# Add a pagination to drupal nodes?

Tags: views, nodes, paging

I can't get a pagination working for my nodes...

What I've tried:
I tried to make a page view with views in which I had my youtube content type and the title. Then there was a pagination but first: It wouldn't apply the normal links of the nodes(veague-0, veague-1, and so on), when i click on "next", but rather the new name of the page(let's say it was "home" then it goes to "home-1" or something)... But the main problem was: The share links weren't there :-(...

I've tried the module smart pagination and it didn't work, it would always just show "" as plain text... I've already adjusted everything which has been told in the main post for smart pagination(https://drupal.org/node/1093856#comment-4223874)

The page I mean is the following:

http://veagues.com

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Please clarify what you mean by "just fails" and "didn't work". Those are very vague terms that won't help to diagnose your problem, and I doubt you'll get an answer as it's currently written. Include a **full**, detailed description of what you've tried, and it what didn't work. That will help us to identify your specific problem, and give some suggestions to fix it. Thanks